# Launch a viewcontroller in a stack of tabbar controller from background (iOS-Swift)

Tags: ios, swift3

I have a storyboard with tab bar controller and one of the tabs segue to another view controller and so on as show in the picture.
I want to go to the page (3) programmatically in the stack while maintaining the stack of the tab bar controller .
Thanks in advance..[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXAZg.png)

Comment: Where do you want to go from in your storyboard to reach (2)?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i want to go to 3 from App delegate when i receive notification while app is in background

Comment: You cannot perform view-related tasks while in background. You could however perform those tasks once the app is in foreground again.

Comment: OK, i will do this when the app is in foreground but how to do it while maintaining the stack

Answer (score 0):

This one's a little tricky, maybe someone else here knows a better way of doing it but here's how I would tackle the problem. Let's assume for simplicity that all views are loaded already. Let me know if this works

1. Setup an observer in the view controller that is being displayed by the tab selected in the tab bar controller. (Let's call this page TabPageVC). When the event that the TabPageVC is observing is fired have it segue way to page 3 immediately
2. In app delegate when the app becomes active / enters foreground check to see if you need to display page 3. If you do need to then get the root view controller in app delegate (i'm assuming it's the tab bar view controller, if it's not you'll need to set it to be).
3. Set the selected tab in the tab bar controller to be the tab of the index that TabPageVC lives in
4. Trigger that event that TabBarVC is observing this will cause TabBarVC to immediately segue way to page 3 and you'll have retained the stack